# Convert time from numeric to time format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I read data from an xls file. Apparently, the time is not in the right format. It is as follows (for example)

```
0.3840277777777778
0.3847222222222222
0.3854166666666667
```

Indeed, they should be

```
09:12
09:13
09:13
```

I don't know how to convert it to the right format. I searched several threads and all of them are about converting the date (with/without time) to the right format.

Can somebody give me any clues?

Comment: which package/function do you use to read your data from excel? There are several methods

Comment: Hi, I used `read.xlsx2(file dir, sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use as.POSIXct after having multiplied your number by the number of seconds in a day (60 * 60 * 24)

```
nTime <- c(0.3840277777777778, 0.3847222222222222, 0.3854166666666667)
format(as.POSIXct((nTime) * 86400, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M")
## [1] "09:13" "09:14" "09:15"
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for my friend, though it solves the conversion problem somehow. The result is now containing the date of `1970-01-01`, while I actually only want the time value

Comment: You can use substring to extract the time.

nTime <- 0.5;
datePosix <- as.POSIXct((nTime) * 60 * 60 * 24, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC");
substring(datePosix, 12, 19)

Answer (score 12):

Another option is `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
times(nTime)
#[1] 09:13:00 09:14:00 09:15:00
```

To strip off the seconds,

```
substr(times(nTime),1,5)
#[1] "09:13" "09:14" "09:15"
```

#### data

```
nTime <- c(0.3840277777777778, 0.3847222222222222, 0.3854166666666667)
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who want the opposite way: given the 09:13:00, get 0.3840278

```
as.numeric(chron::times("09:13:00"))
```

Essentially, the idea is that one whole day is 1,so noon (12pm) is 0.5.