# R How to convert numerical hour value to %H:%M:%S and add time to a date

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

If  a large data set containing data that resembles

```
  df<-    Energy  Power    StartTime                 Timehour
          7.50    10     2017-10-18 09:47:10.073     0.75
```

1) I want to transfer the time hour data into a time

```
 df<-    Energy  Power    StartTime                  Timehour
          7.50    10     2017-10-18 09:47:10.073     00:45:00
```

2) Then I want to add the Time Hour value to the starttime

```
 df<-    Energy  Power    StartTime                  Timehour     NewTime
          7.50    10     2017-10-18 09:45:10.000     00:45:00      2017-10-18 10:30:10.000
```

For 1) I tried to change the time notation with [Convert time from numeric to time format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043140/convert-time-from-numeric-to-time-format-in-r)

```
       df$Timehour <- as.Date(df$Timehour)
       df$Timehour <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Timehour)*86400, origin = "1970-01-01",tz = "UTC", "%H:%M:%OS")
```

But I receive the following message

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(df$Timehour) :
```

'origin' must be supplied

Can someone help me with my 1st and 2th question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base solution: you need to put your timehour in seconds to add it simply to Posixct

```
df$Timehour <- df$Timehour*3600
df$StartTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$StartTime),format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
df$newtime <- df$StartTime + df$Timehour

  Energy Power           StartTime Timehour             newtime
1    7.5    10 2017-10-18 09:47:10     2700 2017-10-18 10:32:10
```

You can convert your timehour to the desired format this way:

```
df$Timehour <- strftime(as.POSIXct(df$Timehour,origin='1900-01-01 00:00'),format="%H:%M:%S",tz = "GMT")

  Energy Power           StartTime Timehour             newtime
1    7.5    10 2017-10-18 09:47:10 00:45:00 2017-10-18 10:32:10
```

data:

```
df<- read.table(text = "Energy,  Power,    StartTime,                 Timehour
7.50,    10 ,    2017-10-18 09:47:10,    0.75",header = TRUE ,sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your time hour into minutes with lubridate, you can jut add it to the starttime column

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

df <- read_table("Energy  Power    StartTime                 Timehour
7.50    10     2017-10-18 09:47:10.073     0.75")

df %>% mutate(
  minutes = minutes(round(Timehour * 60)),
  newTime = StartTime + minutes)

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  Energy Power StartTime           Timehour minutes      newTime            
   <dbl> <int> <dttm>                 <dbl> <S4: Period> <dttm>             
1   7.50    10 2017-10-18 09:47:10    0.750 45M 0S       2017-10-18 10:32:10
```

If needed, first convert your StartTime column to datatime class with

```
df <- df %>% mutate(StartTime = ymd_hms(StartTime))
```